# mysql is not returning any result

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing the following code in my PHP program, but mysql is NOT returning any row. Kindly check and help to find out the mistakes in the following code.

index.php :

```
<?php

require 'connect.php';
if (!$_POST['submit']) {
    echo "<table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"3\" cellpadding=\"3\"> \n";
    echo "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"index.php\">\n";
    echo "<tr><td>username</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"username\"</td></tr> \n";
    echo "<tr><td colspan=\"2\" align=\"right\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\"</td></tr> \n";
    echo "</form></table> \n";
} else {
    $user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, username);
    $result = $db->query("SELECT id,username FROM members WHERE username=".$user);
    print_r($result);
}
```

connect.php:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'Siload', 'Siload2012', 'users');
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    echo $db->connect_error;
}
?>
```

Comment: `WHERE username='".$user."'"` also start using prepared statements.

Comment: Enable error reporting and check error log.

Comment: Try enable error reporting using `ini_set("display_errors", 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);` and well @AbhikChakraborty 's comment is right

Comment: TRy single quoting your username: `$result = $db->query("SELECT id,username FROM members WHERE username= '$user' ");`

Comment: oh thank you guys the correct answer is 
    "SELECT id,username FROM members WHERE username= '$user' ". but in between when i turn on error_reporting i get another error saying : Use of undefined constant username - assumed 'username' in this line $user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, username); whats that? and does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: try execute your query at database, if it return a result then check your $user ensure it have value

Answer (score 0):

Use `print_r(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));`

Comment: Provide your suggestions/debugs under "comments" section of question. Please remove this, unless this actually solves the problem.

Comment: @Makesh mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in print_r(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are not declaring your variable properly. You are also not building your query correctly. Try this way instead.

```
$user = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $_POST['username']);
$result = $db->query("SELECT id,username FROM members WHERE username='".$user."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

To print any results you need to fetch rows from result because $db->query returns a mysqli_result object which is an iterator, but it doesn't contain any real data yet.

For example: 
`$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
print_r($row);`

[fetch_assoc docs](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

If should also add a check to your $result variable if it equals false. In that case you're getting some error in the query itself. Maybe your DB is unavailable at the moment